# autowire=Autowire.BY_NAME in not working in Spring

Tags: spring

**A.java**

```
package com.jc.beans;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

public class A {
    @Qualifier("b1")
    private B b;

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("starting..");
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A [b=" + b + "]";
    }
}
```

**B.java**

```
package com.jc.beans;

public class B {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
package com.jc.test;

import com.jc.beans.A;
import com.jc.beans.B;

@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "values.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.jc.beans")
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean(name = "b1")
    public B newB1() {
        B b = new B();
        b.setId(10);
        b.setName("Anuj");
        return b;
    }

    @Bean(name = "b2")
    public B newB2() {
        B b = new B();
        b.setId(20);
        b.setName("Awasthi");
        return b;
    }

    @Bean(name = "a", autowire = Autowire.BY_NAME)
    public A newA() {
        A a = new A();
        return a;
    }
}
```

Comment: my Autowire is not working.it is not injecting one bean into another bean

Comment: Format the code in post and add more details

Comment: share your A and B class with configuration you are using.

Comment: @shi I submitted All my code but Autowire is not working in java based Annotation in spring

Comment: @Quaiifier annotation is also not working